# OpenCV installation on Anaconda Windows ImportError

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, anaconda, importerror, conda

I try to install OpenCV but it doesn't work, I get import error:

> from conda.cli.main import main
>   ImportError: No module named conda.cli.main

Comment: I had quite a lot of trouble with Anaconda and OpenCV, [this tutorial](https://rivercitylabs.org/up-and-running-with-opencv3-and-python-3-anaconda-edition/) worked for me, have a look

Comment: Thank you for help. OpenCV started working but I have no idea how it happend. Command **conda** still doesn't work.